# Deserialize an XML file without loading it all in the memory

Tags: c#, .net, performance, memory-management, xml-serialization

Suppose that your application serializes objects using XmlSerializer. When another part of the application (e.g. an external service or another component) process that XML file, gets you back a huge XML file that is a serialization of a huge object.

Which are your approach in deserializing and processing that response without filling your server's memory?

I usually prefer to use the XmlSerializer, but when I have to fight against these monster, I have no bullet-proof solutions. I've read about XNode.ReadFrom, but I'm wondering if using this method I can accomplish like a streaming-deserialization.

Comment: please read [SaxParser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903947/saxparser-equivalent-in-c-sharp)