# How do I extract an XmlElement from an XmlTextReader?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have very large XML files (> 2GB) and if I just try to use XmlDocument.Load() I get an OutOfMemory exception. I want to read the high-level elements in the XML via an XmlTextReader and then use XPath on each high-level element, without having to load the entire XML document into a huge XMLDocument object.

So, for example, if I have an XML file with...

```
<xmlStuff>
  <foo>
    <name>Bob Builder</name>
    <age>23</age>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <name>Steve Austin</name>
    <age>99</age>
  </foo>
</xmlStuff>
```

And I am reading the XML file with XmlTextReader (because the file is so large) once I find a  element I want to load just that 1  element into an XmlElement so I can then parse it via XPath.

Is there a better way to approach this? Can I just perform XPath through an XmlReader or XmlTextReader?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [saxparser equivalent in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903947/saxparser-equivalent-in-c-sharp) and the [article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_data/xml/article.php/c4221/Writing-XML-SAX-Parsers-in-C.htm) it points to.